# Fatal error: opencv2/sfm.hpp: no such file or directory #include <opencv2/sfm.hpp>

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, ubuntu-17.04, opencv-contrib

I'm a beginner with opencv library. I've installed it on Ubuntu 17.04 and everything during the installation was perfect, no error at all.
I've installed the Opencv-master, builded it, then I downloaded the opencv_contrib-master and added it to the build folder.

I'm trying to build the scene_reconstruction using SFM (structure for motion). I've installed all the dependencies with:

```
    sudo apt-get install libeigen3-dev libgflags-dev libgoogle-glog-dev
```

Then I've installed the Ceres Solver:

```
git clone https://ceres-solver.googlesource.com/ceres-solver
cd ceres-solver
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make -j4
make test
sudo make install
```

Everything was ok, no error at all.
I tried to write the example_sfm_scene_reconstruction.cpp following the official documentation from here ([Tutorial Scene Reconstruction](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d18/tutorial_sfm_scene_reconstruction.html)).

With `cmake .` there weren't any errors but when I try to do `make` I've this error:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLGQi.png)

The english version is **fatal error: opencv2/sfm.hpp: no such file or directory  #include**

Maybe the path is not correct or I don't know what to think.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to build the OpenCV Release together with the Contrib Release. To build OpenCV with the Contrib Repository you will have to add a parameter to cmake:

```
cd <opencv_build_directory>
cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=<opencv_contrib>/modules <opencv_source_directory>
make -j5
```

I recommend getting a stable opencv version (e.g. 3.3.1) as opposed to checking out the master branch. Make sure that contrib is the same version. If you are unsure at all, just follow the instructions here:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib

Also, you will need the dependencies for the sfm module before compiling opencv.

Comment: I did it:
cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=opencv_contrib-master/modules ..
Then make -j5, but the error is still the same. I've all the dependencies for sfm. Maybe is the path where I have the .cpp wrong?
I've opencv 3.3.1 installed.